# Swift: Unwrapping Optionals and NSNull

Tags: ios, swift, option-type, unwrap

```
if let action = self.info?["action"] {
    switch action as! String {
        ....
    }
} else {...}
```

In this example, "action" always exists as a key in self.info.

Once the second line executes, I get:

```
Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x1b7f59128) to 'NSString' (0x1b7f8ae8).
```

Any idea how action can be NSNull even though I unwrapped it? I've even tried "if action != nil", but it still somehow slips through and causes a SIGABRT.

Comment: It could be possible that what you are trying to unwrap is not a String

Comment: self.info is a dictionary of type [String : AnyObject], but the value is always a string. Shouldn't forcing the downcast work regardless?

Comment: Why don't you conditional cast action to a String when you declare it? Like this: `if let action = self.info?["action"] as? String {...`

Comment: Not sure which version of Swift you're using but as of Swift 3 `String` doesn't conform to `AnyObject`. Try `[String:Any]` instead.

Comment: Also from the error message you can see that you're getting `NSNull` instead of a string, and checking for `nil` will not help because `NSNull` is an actual object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSNull` is a special value typically resulting from JSON processing. It is very different from a `nil` value. And you can't force-cast an object from one type to another which is why your code fails.

You have a few options. Here's one:

```
let action = self.info?["action"] // An optional
if let action = action as? String {
    // You have your String, process as needed
} else if let action = action as? NSNull {
    // It was "null", process as needed
} else {
    // It is something else, possible nil, process as needed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. So in the first line, check first if there is a valid value for "action", then if that value is in type `String`

```
if let action = self.info?["action"] as? String {
    switch action{
        ....
    }
} else {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if let action = self.info?["action"] { // Unwrap optional

   if action is String {  //Check String

      switch action {
        ....
      }

  } else if action is NSNull { // Check Null

    print("action is NSNull")

  } else {

    print("Action is neither a string nor NSNUll")

  }

} else {

    print("Action is nil")

}
```